# Need XSD Schema catalog for Velocity Template

Tags: velocity, dita

Is there a XSD Schema catalog for velocity template.
Our scenario is such that we want to merge VTL and dita but VTL does not go along with the schema for DITA.
So is there any default XSD schema which we can add to our main catalog so that the files become valid with VTL like #foreach and #if which are written inbetween tags become valid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "technicalContent/dtd/topic.dtd">
<section id="sample">
      <title>samplelist</title>
      <ol>#foreach($issue in $issues)?
        <li>$issue.fields.summary ($issue. Key)</li>
        #end
      </ol>
    </section>
```

Is valid Dita

Answer (score 0):

DITA XML has certain vocabulary constraints. Maybe what you could do would be to insert some HTML content directly inside a DITA topic file using the <foreign> element. Here's a DITA OT publishing plugin which does this:

https://github.com/oxygenxml/dita-embed-html-xslfo